# How to trim the last part of string using Perl?

Tags: perl, trim

I need to trim the last part of the string here. The string i have is : `abc|bcd|cde|`.

I need to get rid of the last `|`... The `trim()` command is not helping for some reason may be i am using it wrong, please help... thank you.

Comment: "The trim() command is not helping for some reason may be i am using it wrong" - Probably because Perl doesn't have a `trim` command :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a simple substitution.

```
my $string = "abc|bcd|cde|";
$string =~ s/\|$//;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [chop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html):

```
my $string = "abc|bcd|cde|";
chop($string);
say $string;
```

**output:**

```
abc|bcd|cde
```

From the doc:

> Chops off the last character of a string and returns the character
>   chopped. It is much more efficient than s/.$//s because it neither
>   scans nor copies the string. If VARIABLE is omitted, chops $_ . If
>   VARIABLE is a hash, it chops the hash's values, but not its keys.

Comment: Thanks to downvoter, but an explanation will be welcome!